# iOS - Is there a way to select a cell but not scroll to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Right now I am using:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Is there another way of selecting cells that does not auto scroll to the newly selected cell's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. In fact, it's in UITableViewScrollPosition enum.

```
UITableViewScrollPositionNone
```

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Passing UITableViewScrollPositionNone will result in no scrolling, rather than the minimum scrolling described for that constant.